# Comparing JSON strings give different results with the same code

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, unit-testing, debugging

So I have a module which retrieves JSON from [Open Weather Map](http://openweathermap.org/api). The user has to input the location and the API key to receive the output for the corresponding location:

**(main module)**

```
def weather_response(location, API_key):
    location=format(location) #Formats the location name if proper form
    url='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q='+location+'&APPID='+API_key
    json=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    json=json.read()
    json=json.decode()
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,"main3.txt")

    return json
```

I also have a testing file for the same:

**(tester module)**

```
def test_weather_response(self):
    global json_de
    global json_ny
    self.assertEqual(weather_response("Delhi","<APPID>"),json_de)
    self.assertNotEqual(weather_response("Mumbai","<APPID>"),json_de)
    self.assertEqual(weather_response("delhi","<APPID>"),json_de)
    self.assertEqual(weather_response("  dElHi    ","<APPID>"),json_de)
    self.assertNotEqual(weather_response("Pizza","<APPID>"),json_de)
```

,where json_de and json_ny are declared as follows:

**(tester module)**

```
url='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Delhi&APPID=<APPID>'
json_de=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
json_de=json_de.read()
json_de=json_de.decode()

url2='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=NewYork&APPID=<APPID>'
json_ny=urllib.request.urlopen(url2)
json_ny=json_ny.read()
json_ny=json_ny.decode()

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,"tested3.txt")
```

As you can see, I have saved the response in each file so that I can track the error when the testing fails.

**Testing_1:**

Result:

[image: Test_1]

Output files:

From the main function: [main.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByPBOyCIZ67cVjA2NWl3X2tJOHM)

From the testing function: [tested.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByPBOyCIZ67cZnNLc0FRRlcxak0)

**Testing_2:**

Result:

[image: Test_2]

Output files:

From the main function: [main2.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByPBOyCIZ67cYjBJMEtkcVNMR0E)

From the testing function: [testing2.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByPBOyCIZ67cYjdJYkNHbjNnRGs)

**Testing_3:**

Result:

[image: Test_3]

Output files:

From the main function: [main3.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByPBOyCIZ67cZDBtTjBIRWFSVTQ)

From the testing function: [testing3.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByPBOyCIZ67calJXc2NjcTdJSUE)

---

Now, I don't know why for the same code, same url and the same output (see text files), I am getting error only in the third execution.

Comment: You are calling an external API; weather forecasts change over time.

Comment: But I am not hardcoding anything into the script. I am calling an external API for every run in both the files.

Comment: Unit testing should never rely on external code, especially external services out of your control producing new data over time. It's not your job to test their API anyway.

Comment: Please explain the downvote too (whosoever did it). It is difficult to understand what I did wrong.

Comment: Yes, you call an external API multiple times, and then your test fails when they suddenly don't return the exact same data for multiple calls. That's not a good test, it's flakey and the wrong thing to cover anyway.

Comment: Exact same data? Like a1 is the data for main file and b1 is for the tester file for run1. ai and bi for ith run. So you are saying that it is possible for ai not being equal to bi?

Comment: https://twitter.com/rebeccaslatkin/status/852627030092939274?lang=en

Comment: Also note that JSON objects aren't ordered, so even if the responses are equivalent they may not be the same exact string.

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan: so what is `assertEqual(weather_response(...), ...)` supposed to do? You are making a network call to an external API, there is **no guarantee** that that data will be the same, *ever*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So that means response to both the files in a single run can be different too, right? But I myself compared main3.txt and tester3.txt. They are completely identical.

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan: what are you really testing here? If the API will return the same result for strings that are padded with whitespace? Why is that your responsibility to test, isn't that up to the API maintainers to test? Focus only on your own code to test.

Comment: Okay, I am confused. Corresponding text file outputs are same. So where is the issue?

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan: where are you testing the text files? That's not what is failing. You are testing if the call to `weather_response()` returns the same data as stored in `json_de`. `weather_response()` does not load a text file.

Comment: In fact, there are **no text files at all** in your unit tests. Just because you managed to save *a* response from an API does not mean that *all* responses from that API will return the same data. Don't test external APIs. Test your own code *only*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I had an assignment, and I am stuck on this. Thing is that in an example, the JSON string of some date and time was hardcoded in the 'expected output' parameter of the tester function. So I thought that it will not work while evaluating my assignment. So I globally defined responses for Delhi and New York and used those to test my function.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Okay. I didn't know that. So is there something like conversion going on before comparing these strings?

Comment: On a separate note: *never put private API keys in your post*. Your API key should never be made public. We have redacted your post to remove the key, but search engines and other scrapers as well as users reading this post before the change could have archived the key. You probably want to revoke the key and generate a new one.

Comment: Oh. I am such a noob. Well thanks! I will do it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153557/discussion-between-reeshabh-ranjan-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was the message ID attached with each response:

[image: message ID with the JSON string]

I skipped scanning that very line and problem got solved.